# How is ndb.StringProperty equals a python string?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, app-engine-ndb

I have this ndb Model class

```
class foo(ndb.Model):
  abc = ndb.StringProperty()
```

Now when I used `abc` like this:

```
if foo.abc == "a":
  print "I'm in!"
```

It gets into the if block and prints `I'm in!`

How's this possible?

I also tried printing `foo.abc`, it returned `StringProperty('abc')`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to instantiate an instance of class to use properties properly.

```
class Foo(ndb.Model):
  abc = ndb.StringProperty()

foo = Foo()
foo.abc = 'some val'
print foo.abc  # prints 'some val'
print foo.abc == 'a' # prints False
print Foo.abc == 'a' # prints something not boolean - can't check now.
```

You are are getting `"I'm in!"` because ndb properties are overwriting `__equal__` operator and returning a non empty object that is treated as `True`. This is used to make queries like `query.filter(foo.abc == 'def')`

Comment: So, this statement evaluates to `if StringProperty('abc') == "a"` which is `True` but when I write `if foo(abc='bar') == "a"` or `if foo('xyz') == "a"` given that `class foo` is having a proper constructor for handling this argument. It doesn't comes to be `True`

Comment: It's never True. It is treated as True in IF statement. Try `if 'abc'`. In Python None, empty strings, 0, empty list, empty tuple, empty set are treated as False. Others as True in boolean expresions. Unless __equal__ overwritten.